# Addition of a Sequence of Cardinals

Tags: set-theory

In Keith Devlin's book, "The joy of sets", he says that given a sequence of cardinals $\langle\kappa{_{\alpha}\vert\alpha<\beta}\rangle$, the sum of the cardinals $\sum_{\alpha<\beta}\kappa_{\alpha}$ is defined to be $\vert\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta}\kappa_{\alpha}\times{\{\alpha\}}\vert$ where the $\kappa_{\alpha}$ are regarded as sets in the definition.

He then claims that: By the manipulation of bijections it is easily seen that $\sum_{\alpha<\beta}\kappa_{\alpha}=\vert\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta}{A_{\alpha}}\vert$ where $\langle A{_{\alpha}\vert\alpha<\beta}\rangle$ is any set of pairwise disjoint sets with $\kappa_{\alpha}=\vert{A_{\alpha}\vert }$ for all $\alpha<\beta$ (This follows by picking a family of bijections $f_{\alpha}:A_{\alpha}\rightarrow\kappa_{\alpha}\times\{\alpha\}$ using AC and then noting that $\bigcup{f_{\alpha}}$ gives a bijection between the required sets).

He then goes on to say that: Let $\langle\kappa{_{\alpha}\vert\alpha<\beta}\rangle$ be any sequence of cardinals and let $\langle\lambda{_{\gamma}\vert\gamma<\delta}\rangle$ be a rearrangement of this sequence (He does not define what a rearrangement is but I'm assuming it means that there is bijection between $\delta$ and $\beta$.) Then $\sum_{\alpha<\beta}\kappa_{\alpha} = \sum_{\gamma<\delta}\lambda_{\gamma}$.

He does not prove this result. My question is how would you try and prove this? The sets $\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta}\kappa_{\alpha}\times{\{\alpha\}}$ and $\bigcup_{\gamma<\delta}\lambda_{\gamma}\times{\{\gamma\}}$ need not be equal or they do not even have to be subsets of each other. My attempts at using AC and/or recursion to define a bijection also failed (My idea was to claim that, given $\gamma<\delta$, there existed $\alpha<\beta$ s.t. $\vert\kappa_{\alpha}\times\{\alpha\}=\lambda_{\gamma}\times{\{\gamma\}}$ and some how use this in conjunction with recursion to get a bijection. I also tried some variants of the idea: The interesting case is when the ordinals indexing the sequence are infinite. So wlog I may assume that $\nu\leq{\delta}\leq\beta$ where $\nu$ is the greatest cardinal below $\delta$ and $\beta$. However I couldn't get this idea to work either.)

Comment: Isn't it obvious? There's a bijection between them so the sum is the same.

Comment: What is the bijection though? I got stuck on the details when trying to construct one. If you can construct one that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: My definition for "rearrangement" is weaker than what you have here and the following hint, given in the answer by Cameron. If I adapt the definition in the hint, it works fine. Even if we take your statement you have here for granted things aren't as easy as would like them to be. For example $\lambda_{0}=\aleph_{1}$ and $\kappa_{0}=\aleph_{0}$ is possible. How do you properly glue your partial bijections together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: When he says that $\langle\lambda_\gamma\mid\gamma<\delta\rangle$ is a rearrangement of $\langle\kappa_\alpha\mid\alpha<\beta\rangle$, he means that there is a bijective function $\sigma:\beta\to\delta$ such that for all $\alpha<\beta$ we have $\kappa_\alpha=\lambda_{\sigma(\alpha)}.$ Do you see how to use $\sigma$ construct the desired bijection between $\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta}\kappa_\alpha\times\{\alpha\}$ and $\bigcup_{\gamma<\delta}\lambda_\gamma\times\{\gamma\}$?

Comment: If that is what is meant by rearrangement then this should work. However I thought it meant that there is bijection between $\delta$ and $\beta$. Your statement looks like it is strictly stronger. Also what about my comment about AC and the linked question?

Comment: It is, indeed, strictly stronger. It's not just that we can put $\beta$ and $\delta$ into bijection. Rather, it is that we can put the cardinals in the two sequences into bijection (which certainly requires that $\beta$ and $\delta$ can be put into bijection). For example, taking $\kappa_n=n$ for each $n<\omega$ and $\lambda_n=\aleph_n$ for each $n<\omega,$ the sequence $\langle\lambda_n\mid n<\omega\rangle$ is *not* a rearrangement of $\langle\kappa_n\mid n<\omega\rangle,$ even though $\omega$ is of course in bijection with itself.

Comment: AC shouldn't come into play anywhere in this proof. The only place it comes into play in the results you mentioned above (unless I'm mistaken) is in choosing the bijections $f_\alpha:A_\alpha\to\kappa_\alpha\times\{\alpha\}$ in order to prove the second result. The proof of regularity of successor cardinals can use AC in one of several different ways, but I don't have Devlin's book, so I can't say which.

Comment: Thank you. After your second comment I realize now that I should have seen that to be the definition of a rearrangement. But with regards to the linked question I'm still stumped with the proof in the book.